# jQuery : Event for a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newbie to jQuery and loves it

Can any one give me a small jQuery code snippet to Show an alert/Div when a button (with id btnSave ) being clicked .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```js
$('#btnSave').click( function() {
  $('#alert').show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='alert'>ALERT!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $("#btnSave").click(function() {
    alert("Alert");
  });
});
```

or

```
<div id="alert">
<p>Some alert.</p>
<input type="button" id="ok" value="OK">
</div>
```

with:

```
$(function() {
  $("#btnSave").click(function() {
    $("#alert").show();
  });
  $("#ok").click(function() {
    $("#alert").hide();
  });
});
```

**Note:** I wouldn't actually do it that way. Instead I'd use an existing plug-in like [jQuery UI dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog).